# Scichart Display series markers on YAxis for each DataSerie C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, scichart

I'm creating a chart using scichart. I want to display some markers (eg. small Ellipses) on Yaxis for every Data Series depending on where the cursor is.

So far by using:

```
<s:SciChartSurface.ChartModifier>
   <s:ModifierGroup>
      <s:CursorModifier/>
   </s:ModifierGroup>
</s:SciChartSurface.ChartModifier>
```

I've obtained a cursor that marks the datapoints directly on charts.

Here is a picture of what I want to obtain (see the markers on Yaxis):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Interesting requirement! In SciChart the [RolloverModifier](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/v4.x/RolloverModifier.html) exposes a [collection of SeriesInfo](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/v4.x/SeriesInfo%20%E2%80%93%20the%20ViewModels%20for%20Tooltips%20and%20Legends.html) - which are ViewModels used by all the cursor and legend types in SciChart.

[image]

You can bind anything to this data-source. The [XySeriesInfo](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/v4.x/webframe.html#SciChart.Charting~SciChart.Charting.Model.ChartData.XySeriesInfo.html) itself contains information about the series being viewed. For example, the SeriesName, the SeriesColor, the X,Y Values etc...

[image]

So, if you can bind to this collection of SeriesInfo as a data-source and create and add [AxisMarkerAnnotations](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/v4.x/webframe.html#The%20AxisMarkerAnnotation%20Type.html) to the axis at the specified Y-Value then you can achieve what you want. The only problem is the Axis Markers will only be visible when the tooltips are visible.

[image]

For an idea of how to pull this together, consider creating your code to bind to SeriesInfo and add AxisMarkerAnnotations in a custom ChartModifier. *(See the [Custom ChartModifierBase API documentation](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/v4.x/Custom_Modifiers_%E2%80%93_ChartModifierBase_API.html) for details on this powerful and flexible API.)*

Comment: Thank for your answer. I Have another question - how to bind `SeriesInfo`? I've tried to bind `SeriesData` (`<s:RolloverModifier Width="3" Height="3" ShowTooltipOn="MouseRightButtonDown" 
                                        SeriesData="{Binding RollOverModifierSeriesData, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>`), but the debugger returns a nullReference error when reaching this point.

Comment: You know how Stackoverflow works right? It's one question / multiple answers. If you have a new Q I suggest creating one and formulating the question well with what you have tried etc...